# Hi all! I have got a problem with verification of the contract on BSCScan ! Can some one explain me the problem please?

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, openzeppelin, bscscan

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
--> myc:4:1:
|
4 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
--> myc:5:1:
|
5 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/access/Ownable.sol"
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying from local machine and not remix IDE then what you can do is flatten your code using sol-merger.
To install sol-merger you can do `npm install -g sol-merger`.
And to flatten the file you can do `sol-merger <your-contract-with-fullpath> <new-location-to-store-flatten-file>`

- Ex. `sol-merger ./contract/test.sol ./build`
- Or you can do is use [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/verifying) or truffle plugins to verify your contracts.
- You can reference this also [ref](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-verify-with-hardhat-or-truffle-a-smart-contract-using-openzeppelin-contracts/4119)
- In this example I assume that you already install node_modules of `@openzeppelin/contracts` in your local.

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/access/Ownable.sol";


/// @custom:security-contact p*********@gmail.com
contract U********** is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("Uranium238", "U238") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 500000000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}

Comment: That is my contract